# Downsides of pip install <url>?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have recently started using Golang and I am impressed by how the "go get" command can install packages from VCS. Then I came across the gopkg.in website which creates nicely formatted URLs for these repositories.

Personally I use Python a lot and the process of publishing packages to PyPI seems to be quite some work. I know "pip install <*url*>" works. But is there any downsides?

To elaborate more, I have a domain name: pypi.xyz and I would like allow short urls like: pypi.xyz/user/package so people can install it like this: "pip install pypi.xyz/user/package". The URL will infact point to a tar.gz archive from github.

I have tested the concept with a bit.ly short url. So I know it works. But I am wondering if people would not be interested or if there are obvious downsides of this process.

I am new to Python, so please accept my apologies if this is a dumb idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Personally I use Python a lot and the process of publishing packages to PyPI seems to be quite some work.

Except it isn’t.  If you do the initial setup right (sensible `MANIFEST.in`, **one-time** package registration, pypi credentials setup, `pip install twine wheel`, optional PGP setup), it’s as easy as

```
./setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload -s dist/mypackage-0.1.0*
```

And you can write a shell alias to automate that.

> To elaborate more, I have a domain name: pypi.xyz and I would like allow short urls like: pypi.xyz/user/package so people can install it like this: "pip install pypi.xyz/user/package". The URL will infact point to a tar.gz archive from github.

This is a waste of time and $15.  Writing out a GitHub git URL is:

- simpler (not that much typing)
- can be replaced by a simple shell function that would take username/repo, would add the rest and run pip install
- faster (GitHub does not need to produce a tarball for you)
- trusted by people (unlike some shady `pypi.xyz` domain)

What’s more is, good software development practices include having **stable releases**, usually available for download forever. Please keep that in mind, don’t do git-only distribution.

PyPI uploads really are the way to go.